# Need to do a right trim on ajax query in javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace

In JavaScript, I wanted to do the right trim for all the special characters at the end of the string.
My Piece of code doing the trim for hyphen (-) only..Need for all the special characters(:.,()+-=/[]\@#$%^&*) as well.

```
var s = "DB-";
var x = s.replace(/-+$/,'');
console.log(x);
```

Any help on this?

Comment: The same way I have to add all the special characters like s.replace(/-,:/()@#$%^&*()+$/,'') to do trim at the end of the string.

Comment: Yes, but some of those have special meaning in a regex, so you have to escape them

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ttpy0stn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
var x = "abcde#$@asbd#$^@$";
x.slice(0,x.search(/\W*$/));
```

This will only trim off the special characters at the end of the string. It will leave special characters that are in the body of the string.