# Wanted to check whether string ends with special character or not?

Tags: javascript, trim

I wanted to check whether my string which ends with special character or not. If my string contains special character at the end, then need to trim at the right. if not, do nothing.

My piece of code:

```
var s = 'acbd@';
var x = 'abcd@e'
```

Expected Result:

```
acbd
abcd@e
```

any help on this?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything at all?

Comment: Does'nt your provious question [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398395/need-to-do-a-right-trim-on-ajax-query-in-javascript) do exactly that ?

Comment: Sorry..actually the special character is always replace at the end and fails my query. If my string contains special character with other characters at the end (For Ex. abcd@e)..then I need to take the special character as well on the query to get the result from backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to replace the special characters with empty string, like this:

```
s.replace(/[@]+$/, "");
x.replace(/[@]+$/, "");
```

You can specify more special characters inside of square brackets.

Comment: I have replace only string ends with special character..otherwise I have to take that value to back-end query to get the result.

Comment: This regular expression will only replace the specified characters which are in the end of the string.